# Is there a way to catch the output in lua?

Tags: lua, load, lua-5.2

I'm trying to catch the output from for example: print('Hello') and store it in a variable / table.

Please let me know if this is even possible. If not thanks for answering.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. You seem to be asking for a way to intercept output, but [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) is unrelated to output. In your example, `print` returns nothing, but `load` requires a string or function argument.

Comment: I'm trying to catch the output from for example print('Hello') and store it in a variable/table, sorry for bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't intercept standard output directly, but you can change the global `print` function:

```
local outputs = {}
local function storeOutputs(...)
  table.insert(outputs, {...})
end

local oldPrint = print
function print(...)
  storeOutputs(...)
  oldPrint(...)
end
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to deal with `io.write` calls.

Comment: Assigning to `io.stdout` does not affect `io.write()` behavior.  Lua does not use `io.stdout` (situation very similar to `_G`)

Comment: Thanks for answering so quick, and with exacly what I wanted!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Bummer. I'll have to delete that part of my answer for now. There might be a more complicated way to do it, like rewriting all of the output-related `io` functions.

Comment: @luther - See `io.output()`